# Webconfig vs db4o

Tags: .net, web-config, db4o

Has anyone used db4o for storing adhoc or key value pairs that pollute the configuration in the WebConfig ?? I have seen many web config files grow really big in size because it has insane amount of keys and kinda ahem..global variables. Has anyone done this or used db4o to save lookup data on client side in rich client scenario?

Good idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you storing in the web config. Yes, it there a tendency to get bigger, due to new sections for new libraries etc. But that big?

Anyway. I'm not sure if that's an all that great idea. Here my reasoning:

- usually the configuration is human readable, so that you can look into it, change it etc. A db4o file is not human readable. You always need to go through the db4o API.
- db4o is an overkill, and may brings new issues. For example with db4o you have to deal with activation, etc. This is just overkill for something like a configuration file.b

Can't you split the web config file? Or look for a tiny library witch is more specific for configuration related data. (like [Nini](http://nini.sourceforge.net/). Never used myself, probably other alternative exist)